# Back to previous activity

Tags: android

I have a back button that will work exactly like that.
I know using back button is not a good android practice since android device have one. But my situation badly need it.
I cannot finish my activity and its tough to Keep track of the activity stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its better for you to user `super.onBackPressed()`
Refer [Go back to previous activity](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/04/go-back-to-previous-activity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that overriding BACK button function is not a good practice, just follow it. Tracking activity stack and promising the BACK behavior can be solved by properly setting the launch mode of each Activity. (please see: [Launch Mode in Android Official Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode))

If you insist to do something like pressing the BACK button, it's `super.onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you wouldn't want to finish your activity.   Could you move whatever it is in your activity you don't want to destroy into another object?

BTW: the activity will also be destroyed and re created if the screen is rotated.